# Invalid column name, on select-statement created columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have simplified my problem to the following select statement.

```
select 
   u.UserId,
   aVariable = cast((case when exists(select * from TblUser u where u.Disabled=1) then 1 else 0 end) as bit), 
from TblUser u
where aVariable = 1
```

aVariable is not a column of a table, but just a column that gets a value in this select statement.

Is there a way to do the above without getting the 
Invalid column name aVariable error?

Comment: The example doesn't make much sense, even if it were correct syntax, it's effectively the same as saying "where 1=1". Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: you need the update statement -- see my answer.

Comment: I don't understand how the answer you picked as correct works -- see my edited answer.

Comment: @Hogan: Forget the logic inside the sql-statement. What I needed was about syntax. It was about how to use a select-statement-column in my "where" clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select q.* from (
select 
   u.UserId,
   cast((case when exists(select * from TblUser u where u.Disabled=1) then 1 else 0 end) as bit) as aVar, 
from TblUser u
)q 
where q.aVar = 1
```

Comment: I have edited this so it should work now.  SQL was missing a table alias.

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT` must look like so:

```
select 
   u.UserId,
   1 as aVariable
from TblUser u
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement you picked as correct makes no sense.

```
select q.* from (
select 
   u.UserId,
   cast((case when exists(select * from TblUser u where u.Disabled=1) then 1 else 0 end) as bit) as aVar, 
from TblUser u
)q 
where q.aVar = 1
```

The statement above says select all users from the tbluser if there is one user who is disabled.

I think you want to see the users in the table who are disabled.  If that is so then you want the following select statement:

```
SELECT userid, disabled as aVar
FROM TblUser
WHERE disabled = 1
```

Give this a shot.

Prior answered deleted since the question is a tad unclear.

Comment: aVariable is not a parameter, it's a column name and I want to use it in a where clause.

Comment: you can't change column values in a select statement -- you can only read values... if you want a new output column use `as` if you want to change the table use update.

Comment: Invalid column name 'aVariable'. :(

Comment: does your table have a column named avariable?  if it does not have it you can't change it.

Comment: using the @ sign as a prefix is not only for parameters, it is also used for local variables.  if you want a local variable you need to prefix it with an @ and have a declare statement.

Comment: aVariable is not a column of a table, but just a column that gets a value in this select statement.

Comment: Forget the logic inside the sql-statement. What I needed was about syntax. It was about how to use a select-statement-column in my "where" clause.

Comment: @stavros : maybe you mean a select statement that has a case?  But there is no magic -- just include the logic in the where statement, it works find.  Anything in the select statement can also be in the where clause, there is no trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
select 
   u.UserId,
   aVariable = cast((case when exists(select * from TblUser u where u.Disabled=1) then 1 else 0 end) as bit), 
from TblUser u
where cast((case when exists(select * from TblUser u where u.Disabled=1) then 1 else 0 end) as bit) = 1
```

Comment: I was looking for something better, because the select statement inside the case block, is more complicated and slow :(

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the case statement in to a function - that may speed it up.  It will certainly make it more readable.  Are you able to actually post the real problem.  Someone maybe be able to provide a different solution all together.